# How to get text following a span with BeautifulSoup and Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want only the text outside the spans and nothing inside the spans. My current code gives me all of it:

```
birthday = bsObj.find( "div", {"class":"age"} )
# <div class="age"><span class="category">Age:</span> 23 (10/21/1992)</div>
birthday.get_text()
birthplace = bsObj.find( "div", {"class":"hometown"} )
# <div class="hometown"><span class="category">Birthplace:</span> Barranquilla, Colombia</div>
birthplace.get_text()
```

Result:

```
"Age: 24 (04/21/1991)","Birthplace: Barranquilla, Colombia"
```

Desired result:

```
"24 (04/21/1991)","Barranquilla, Colombia"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just clear the span before get_text()

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc ='<html><body><div class="age"><span class="category">Age:</span> 23 (10/21/1992)</div><div class="hometown"><span class="category">Birthplace:</span> Barranquilla, Colombia</div></body></html>'

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

# <div class="age"><span class="category">Age:</span> 23 (10/21/1992)</div>
birthday = bsObj.find( "div", {"class":"age"} )
birthday.span.clear()
print(birthday.get_text()) # 23 (10/21/1992)

# <div class="hometown"><span class="category">Birthplace:</span> Barranquilla, Colombia</div>
birthplace = bsObj.find( "div", {"class":"hometown"} )
birthplace.span.clear()
print(birthplace.get_text()) # Barranquilla, Colombia
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the `span` with `clear()`
- Remove leading and trailing whitespace with `strip()`

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="age"><span class="category">Age:</span> 23 (10/21/1992)</div>', 'html.parser')
soup.span.clear()
print(soup.get_text().strip())
```

Output:

```
23 (10/21/1992)
```